# Dynamically changing bar chart colours, based on Y-axis cell colours

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, bar-chart

I have column A, which has data in groups, for example, Andrew (a), Brian (b), Chloe (c), Diana (a), and so on (about 50 entries like this). In column B, they all have their respective scores, but the matching groups are of the same colours in cell A. For example, all (a)s are red, and all (b)s are orange, and so on. Then I make a bar chart for each individual, where the Y-axis are their names, and the X-axis are their individual scores. So I formatted the bar colours to follow their group name, and I currently do this using data points (it was tedious). Occasionally I will sort by the score to do some analysis. When this sorting changes, my colours on the bar chart gets "scrambled". Is there another way to assign bar chart colours that would help me address the "scrambling" issue?

[Sample Bar Chart & Table][image: 1]

| Name | Score |
| --- | --- |
| Andrew (a) | 234 |
| Brian (b) | 352 |
| Chloe (c) | 456 |
| Diana (a) | 543 |
| Emanuel (b) | 241 |
| Fiona (c) | 356 |
| Gabriel (a) | 256 |
| Hermione (b) | 245 |
| Illiyana (c) | 345 |
| Jacob (a) | 145 |
| Kane (b) | 123 |
| Louis (c) | 134 |

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Have you attempted a script? You would try to use a `onChange` trigger to modify the colors programmatically.

Comment: Nope, the only thing I've done on script is to create a +1 & -1 button :D. Thanks, I'll start looking it up. Feel free to point out any helpful guides if there are any good ones :)

Comment: See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Comment: Could you share a sample sheet to check what would be the data sample you are working on?

Comment: [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R4TZDJeuKNxz-jTHOJ5kVU539QRLPWx2Qi4yuSx4tgg/)

Comment: @TheMaster I can't seem to pull it off, it seems to require that I learn how to code in App Scripts. The code for my +/- 1 buttons were copied from the internet. Could you help me out with the sheet I linked above? :) Thanks in advance

Comment: @Dzcheko Apologies, but that is real work and would require some real time put in.

Comment: Ok :) I'll continue learning how to code in App Script. So far I've managed to understand my +/- 1 buttons. When I get to my charts, I'll post the solution here for future users to refer to.